# onSnapshot() in firebase giving error: undefined is not a function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting this error when the realtime listener is enabled using `onSnapshot()`:
[image]
**EDIT**
**Error:**  WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 5):
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...}).catch(function (err) {...')
fetchFriends$@http://localhost:8081/screens/AllFriends.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=true&runModule=false&shallow=true:92:25
tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:29289:23

This is code the producing the error:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchFriends()
      .then(() =>
        this.setState({
          friends: this.tempFriends,
        }),
      )
      .then(() => this.fetchEachFriend());
  }

  async fetchFriends() {
    const uid = auth().currentUser.uid;
    await firestore()
      .collection('Friendships')
      .where('uid1', '==', `${uid}`)
      .onSnapshot(doc => {                      //Realtime listener
        if (doc.empty) {
          null;
          console.log('DOC: ', doc.empty);
        } else {
          doc.forEach(snap => {
            console.log(snap.data().uid2);
            this.tempFriends.push(snap.data().uid2);
            console.log(this.tempFriends);
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Error DOC1 ', err));
    await firestore()
      .collection('Friendships')
      .where('uid2', '==', `${uid}`)
      .onSnapshot(doc => {                             //realtime listener
        if (doc.empty) {
          null;
          console.log('DOC2: ', doc.empty);
        } else {
          doc.forEach(snap => {
            console.log(snap.data().uid1);
            this.tempFriends.push(snap.data().uid1);
            console.log(this.tempFriends);
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Error DOC2 ', err));
  }

  fetchEachFriend() {
    this.state.friends.forEach(uid => {
      console.log('UID: ', uid);
      firestore()
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(`${uid}`)
        .onSnapshot(doc => {                                  //realtime listener
          console.log('Friend Data ', doc.data());
          this.tempFriendsData.push({
            uid: doc.id,
            data: doc.data(),
          });
        })
        .then(() => this.setState({friendsData: this.tempFriendsData}))
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error fetchEachFriend(): ', err);
        });
    });
  }
```

Below is the code that is not producing any errors, when realtime listener is disable and I am using get() and then() to retrive the data from the db.

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchFriends()
      .then(() =>
        this.setState({
          friends: this.tempFriends,
        }),
      )
      .then(() => this.fetchEachFriend());
  }

  async fetchFriends() {
    const uid = auth().currentUser.uid;
    await firestore()
      .collection('Friendships')
      .where('uid1', '==', `${uid}`)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        //Realtime listener
        if (doc.empty) {
          null;
          console.log('DOC: ', doc.empty);
        } else {
          doc.forEach(snap => {
            console.log(snap.data().uid2);
            this.tempFriends.push(snap.data().uid2);
            console.log(this.tempFriends);
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Error DOC1 ', err));
    await firestore()
      .collection('Friendships')
      .where('uid2', '==', `${uid}`)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        //realtime listener
        if (doc.empty) {
          null;
          console.log('DOC2: ', doc.empty);
        } else {
          doc.forEach(snap => {
            console.log(snap.data().uid1);
            this.tempFriends.push(snap.data().uid1);
            console.log(this.tempFriends);
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Error DOC2 ', err));
  }

  fetchEachFriend() {
    this.state.friends.forEach(uid => {
      console.log('UID: ', uid);
      firestore()
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(`${uid}`)
        //realtime listener
        .get()
        .then(doc => {
          console.log('Friend Data ', doc.data());
          this.tempFriendsData.push({
            uid: doc.id,
            data: doc.data(),
          });
        })
        .then(() => this.setState({friendsData: this.tempFriendsData}))
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error fetchEachFriend(): ', err);
        });
    });
```

I wish to enable realtime listeners. Please help me. Thank you.

**EDIT**: Removed 'await', but still getting the same error. Code after removing 'await':

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchFriends()
      .then(() =>
        this.setState({
          friends: this.tempFriends,
        }),
      )
      .then(() => this.fetchEachFriend());
  }

  fetchFriends() { //Error appearing here
    const uid = auth().currentUser.uid;
    firestore()
      .collection('Friendships')
      .where('uid1', '==', `${uid}`)
      .onSnapshot(doc => { //More precisely error is here
        if (doc.empty) {
          null;
          console.log('DOC: ', doc.empty);
        } else {
          doc.forEach(snap => {
            console.log(snap.data().uid2);
            this.tempFriends.push(snap.data().uid2);
            console.log(this.tempFriends);
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Error DOC1 ', err));
    firestore()
      .collection('Friendships')
      .where('uid2', '==', `${uid}`)
      .onSnapshot(doc => {
        if (doc.empty) {
          null;
          console.log('DOC2: ', doc.empty);
        } else {
          doc.forEach(snap => {
            console.log(snap.data().uid1);
            this.tempFriends.push(snap.data().uid1);
            console.log(this.tempFriends);
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Error DOC2 ', err));
  }

  fetchEachFriend() {
    this.state.friends.forEach(uid => {
      console.log('UID: ', uid);
      firestore()
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(`${uid}`)
        .onSnapshot(doc => {
          console.log('Friend Data ', doc.data());
          this.tempFriendsData.push({
            uid: doc.id,
            data: doc.data(),
          });
        })
        .then(() => this.setState({friendsData: this.tempFriendsData}))
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error fetchEachFriend(): ', err);
        });
    });
  }
```

EDIT: Debugger is pointing to the first line of the file, I'm totally consfused now:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: Please don't show images of text.  It's better to copy the text into the question so it's easier to read and search.  Your question should also help us understand what line of code the error is on, and what you've tried to do already to debug the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question with text

Comment: onSnapshot doesn't return a promise.  It can't be awaited.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query.html#onsnapshot

Comment: I removed ```await``` but i am still getting the same error

Comment: You haven't said what line the error is on.  Where are we supposed to direct our attention?

Comment: Sorry, the error is precisely appearing on the ```onSnapshot()``` in the ```fetchFriends()``` block

Comment: Which specific line?  Use a debugger to figure out the exact line of failure, and the observed conditions for that failure.

Comment: Debugger is pointing to the first line of the file, I'm extremely sorry for the inconvenience caused

Comment: You just posted an error that's different than the one in the title.  Sounds like a whole different issue now.

Comment: Yeah, I know I'm confused. But can you please try and help me out??

Comment: I suggest asking a new question the reflects your current concerns rather that mixing up potentially unrelated issues in the same post.